# How can I READ list of jars from a file and use it as classpath in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle

Let say I have a file `listofjars.txt`, which contain location of `.jar` files on my local file system

```
lib/jarfile1.jar
lib/jarfile2.jar
```

Now I want to read this file and use it during compilation of my project as classpath, how this can be done using Gradle?

Comment: just out of interest, what is the reason to do it?

Comment: apply plugin : "java";

def List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

task readFile << {

        new File('jarfile.txt').eachLine { line ->
                list.add(line);
        }       
        
}

dependencies() {

        compile files(list);

}

Comment: @Stanislav : My project uses around 40 plus jar files which are on local file system , so instead of adding each jar in compile task , I want to put the dependencies in an external file and read it form there.Which i feel is easy to maintain than adding comma separated jar file as compile files(jar1,jar2,jar3,jar4) .

Comment: If all your jars are in the same folder, you could add `compile fileTree('lib')` to your `dependencies` configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
apply plugin: "java";

def List < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();

task readFile << {

  new File('jarfile.txt').eachLine {
    line - >
      list.add(line);
  }

}

dependencies() {

  compile files(list);

}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src';
    }
  }
}

init {
  new File('jarfile.txt').eachLine {
    line - >
      if (!line.equals(""))
        list.add(line);

  }
```